# Django's view of its models is inconsistent with the actual database

Tags: django, postgresql, aws-lambda

We have a system consisting of a Django server connected to a PostgreSQL database, and some AWS Lambda functions which need to access the database. When an admin saves a model (PremiumUser - contains premium plan information that needs to be read by the Lambdas), we want to set up a schedule of CloudWatch events based on the saved information. Those events then trigger other Lambdas which also need to directly access the database, as the database state may change at any time and they should work off the most recent state of the database.

The issue is that Django seems to think it has saved the values, but when the Lambdas read the database the expected values aren't there. We have tried using Django's `post_save` signal, calling the Lambdas inside the triggered function; we have tried overriding Django's default `PremiumUser.save` method to perform `super(PremiumUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)`, and only *then* call Lambdas (in case the `post_save` signal was getting triggered too early); and we have tried overriding the `PremiumUser.save` method and calling `super(PremiumUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)` in the context of an atomic transaction (ie `with transactions.atomic():`).

When we call the Lambdas a few seconds after the admin dashboard has updated, they can find the values as expected and work properly, which suggests that somehow Django considers the model as having been 'saved' to the database, while the database has not yet been updated.

Is there a way to force Django to write to the database immediately? This would be the preferred solution, as it would keep Django's model and the database consistent.

An alternative solution we have considered but would prefer not to resort to would be to put a `sleep` in the Lambdas and calling them asynchronously so that Django's save is able to complete before the Lambda functions access the database. Obviously this would be a race condition, so we don't want to do this if it can be at all avoided.

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after spending more time poring over Django's documentation we found a solution: using `on_commit`. It seems that `post_save` is triggered after Django's *model* is updated, but before the database has been written to. `on_commit`, on that other hand is triggered after the current database transaction has been committed (completed).

For us, the solution involved setting up some code like this:

```
from django.db import models, transaction

class PremiumUser(models.Model):
    # Normal setup code...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # Do some necessary things before the actual save occurs

        super(PremiumUser, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        # Set up a callback for the on_commit
        def create_new_schedule():
            # Call lambda to create new schedule...

        # Register the callback with the current transaction's on_commit
        transaction.on_commit(create_new_schedule)
```